# how to select the two different class inside a parent class?

Tags: css

I'm trying to select the class `.signup-choose-subtitle` and `.signup-choose-list li` in my parent class of `signup-choose-card-content` to apply the font-family.

This is my code in css

```
.ja_jp 
.signup-container 
.signup-content 
.signup-choose-card-content 
.signup-choose-subtitle 
.signup-choose-list li 
{   
    font-family: "M+1C", Roboto, sans-serif; 
}
```

and code in the html

```
<div class="signup-choose-card-content">
   <p class="signup-choose-subtitle" translate="">Easy registration in 15 seconds! Play now!</p>
   <p class="signup-choose-text-highlight">Lite</p>

   <ul class="signup-choose-list">
       <li translate="">No identity verification required</li>
       <li translate="">Over 2,000 games</li>
   </ul>
</div>
```

My goal is to overwrite the existing `font-family: "Bahnschrift", Roboto, sans-serif;` to `font-family: "M+1C", Roboto, sans-serif;` like this image:

[image: [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/5qAfM.png]

Comment: You may try [`:is()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:is) pseudo class: `.signup-choose-card-content :is(.signup-choose-subtitle, .signup-choose-list li)`

Comment: You can put the font family in signup-choose-card-content and it will be applied even for the children, if not you can add (.signup-choose-card-content p) to apply it for all paragraphs inside it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Option 1**

Target specific elements that are nested within the `.signup-choose-card-content` element.

```
.signup-choose-card-content .signup-choose-subtitle,
.signup-choose-card-content .signup-choose-list li {
  font-family: "M+1C", Roboto, sans-serif;
}
```

See the snippet below.

```css
.signup-choose-card-content .signup-choose-subtitle,
.signup-choose-card-content .signup-choose-list li {
  font-family: "M+1C", Roboto, sans-serif;
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="signup-choose-card-content">
  <p class="signup-choose-subtitle" translate="">Easy registration in 15 seconds! Play now!</p>
  <p class="signup-choose-text-highlight">Lite</p>

  <ul class="signup-choose-list">
    <li translate="">No identity verification required</li>
    <li translate="">Over 2,000 games</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

**Option 2**

Target all elements within the `.signup-choose-card-content` element by using the direct child selector (i.e., `>`) except paragraphs with the class `signup-choose-text-highlight`.

```
.signup-choose-card-content > :not(p.signup-choose-text-highlight) {
  font-family: "M+1C", Roboto, sans-serif;
}
```

See the snippet below.

```css
.signup-choose-card-content > :not(p.signup-choose-text-highlight) {
  font-family: "M+1C", Roboto, sans-serif;
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="signup-choose-card-content">
  <p class="signup-choose-subtitle" translate="">Easy registration in 15 seconds! Play now!</p>
  <p class="signup-choose-text-highlight">Lite</p>

  <ul class="signup-choose-list">
    <li translate="">No identity verification required</li>
    <li translate="">Over 2,000 games</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: I'm not sure using `:not()` is a good option here, since OP didn't mention whether there will be other elements inside of `.signup-choose-card-content` or not.

Comment: @HaoWu I agree with you, but my answer is based on the code and information provided in the question.

Comment: the `:not()` is used for what situation? thank you for the answer appreciated.

Comment: @DannJohnremDeGuzman It's just another way to achieve what you want. It depends on your code, but *Option 1* is probably a safer choice.

Comment: Sorry for the lack of information about my question. I just edit it to add some information about the problem, and I hope you understand this is my first time here. thank you

Comment: @DannJohnremDeGuzman I see. Pick *Option 1* and let me know if it solves your problem.

Comment: keep in mind that :not() 'only' has a coverage of 93% of all browser at the moment, see here: https://caniuse.com/?search=not()

Answer (score 0):

According to your description you would probably want it this way (I added the border-property for better visibility druing development):

```
.signup-choose-card-content > .signup-choose-list li,
.signup-choose-card-content > .signup-choose-subtitle {
        border: 4px solid red ;

}
```

With the child combinator you can select direct children of classes/elements etc, see here: [https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Child_combinator](https://MDN%20Web%20Docs)

> The child combinator (>) is placed between two CSS selectors.

Comment: thank you for the answer and appreciated.